# replacing characters by color in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble replacing a "^number" character with color in js.

I have a code in PHP that I am trying to pass to js but I am not successful.

```
<?php

function ColorizeName($s)
{

    $pattern[0] = "^0";
    $replacement[0] = '</font><font color="black">';
    $pattern[1] = "^1";
    $replacement[1] = '</font><font color="red">';
    $pattern[2] = "^2";
    $replacement[2] = '</font><font color="lime">';
    $pattern[3] = "^3";
    $replacement[3] = '</font><font color="yellow">';
    $pattern[4] = "^4";
    $replacement[4] = '</font><font color="blue">';
    $pattern[5] = "^5";
    $replacement[5] = '</font><font color="aqua">';
    $pattern[6] = "^6";
    $replacement[6] = '</font><font color="#FF00FF">';
    $pattern[7] = "^7";
    $replacement[7] = '</font><font color="white">';
    $pattern[8] = "^8";
    $replacement[8] = '</font><font color="white">';
    $pattern[9] = "^9";
    $replacement[9] = '</font><font color="gray">';


    $s = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, htmlspecialchars($s));
    $i = strpos($s, '</font>');
    if ($i !== false) {
        return substr($s, 0, $i) . substr($s, $i + 7, strlen($s)) . '</font>';
    } else {
        return $s;
    }
}
```

I have tried with...

```
function replace(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    if (strArr[i] == '^2') {
      strArr[i].replace('^2', "<font color='blue'> </font>");
    }

    return str;
  }
}
```

what I need is: if you enter a string like this = str "^2 hello ^3 this ^4is a message" the "hello" has to be in lime color, this "this" in yellow color and this "is a message" in blue color

If anyone has any ideas, they are welcome.

Edit.
Solution that worked for me:

```
const colors = ['black', 'red', 'lime', 'yellow', 'blue', 'aqua', '#FF00FF', 'white', 'white', 'gray'];

const text = 'The ^2quick brown ^5fox jumps over the ^9lazy ^6dog.'

const replace = text => 
  // wrap the entire text with <font color="black"></font> if the text contains color code
  text.replace(/^.*\^\d.*$/, '<font color="black">$&</font>')
  // replace the color code with corresponding color tag
  .replace(/\^(\d)/g, (_, num) => `</font><font color="${colors[num]}">`);
const result = replace(text);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your for loop iterates over each character individually. That means your can never match two characters at the same time such as `^2`

Comment: what would be a correct example? str = " ^2hi ^4hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the text that comes after a `^number` depending on the number, you can use the regex: `\^(\d)([^\^]+)`:

```js
function colorizeName(str) {
  const colors = ['black', 'red', 'lime', 'yellow', 'blue', 'aqua', '#FF00FF', 'white', 'white', 'gray'];
  return str.replace(/\^(\d)([^\^]+)/g, (_, n, txt) => `<font color="${colors[+n]}">${txt}</font>`);
}
```

---

Demo:

```js
function colorizeName(str) {
  const colors = ['black', 'red', 'lime', 'yellow', 'blue', 'aqua', '#FF00FF', 'white', 'white', 'gray'];
  return str.replace(/\^(\d)([^\^]+)/g, (_, n, txt) => `<font color="${colors[+n]}">${txt}</font>`);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="^2 hello ^3 this ^4is a message" style="width: 100%; font-size: 16px;">
<button onclick="render.innerHTML = colorizeName(input.value)">Generate</button>
<div id="render"></div>
```

---

If this is for HTML running in a modern browser, it would be much better to use styling instead. You can even make it safer to prevent HTML injection with:

```js
function colorizeName(str) {
  const colors = ['black', 'red', 'lime', 'yellow', 'blue', 'aqua', '#FF00FF', 'white', 'white', 'gray'];
  return str.replace(/\^(\d)([^\^]+)/g, (_, n, txt) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.color = colors[+n];
    span.innerText = txt;
    return span.outerHTML;
  });
}
```

Demo:

```js
function colorizeName(str) {
  const colors = ['black', 'red', 'lime', 'yellow', 'blue', 'aqua', '#FF00FF', 'white', 'white', 'gray'];
  return str.replace(/\^(\d)([^\^]+)/g, (_, n, txt) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.color = colors[+n];
    span.innerText = txt;
    return span.outerHTML;
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="^2 hello ^3 this ^4is a message" style="width: 100%; font-size: 16px;">
<button onclick="render.innerHTML = colorizeName(input.value)">Generate</button>
<div id="render"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may utilize regex to achieve it:

```js
const colors = ['black', 'red', 'lime', 'yellow', 'blue', 'aqua', '#FF00FF', 'white', 'white', 'gray'];

const text = 'The ^2quick brown ^5fox jumps over the ^9lazy ^6dog.'

const replace = text => 
  // wrap the entire text with <font color="black"></font> if the text contains color code
  text.replace(/^.*\^\d.*$/, '<font color="black">$&</font>')
  // replace the color code with corresponding color tag
  .replace(/\^(\d)/g, (_, num) => `</font><font color="${colors[num]}">`);
const result = replace(text);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It works perfect, thank you very much.